# Insert rows into a dataframe by group and entry is from another dataframe_complex match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, match

I wish to insert some entries into a dataframe called 'df_recorded' for each group, and the entry is searched from another dataframe called "df_missed".

```
import pandas as pd

df_recorded = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['2008 11', '2008 11', '2008 11', '2008 07', '2008 07', '2008 12', '2008 12', '2008 12'],
    'info': ['recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', ],
    'score': [98, 68, 79, 75, 66, 62, 60, 60],
    'date' : ['2010-12-10', '2010-10-01', '2010-09-12', '2010-12-10', '2010-11-01', '2010-12-07', '2010-11-10', '2010-09-12']
})

df_missed = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['2008 11', '2008 07', '2008 12'],
    'missed_score': [62, 72, 80],
    'missed_date': ['2010-08-01', '2010-10-20', '2010-07-23']
})


        id      info  score        date
0  2008 11  recorded     98  2010-12-10
1  2008 11  recorded     68  2010-10-01
2  2008 11  recorded     79  2010-09-12
3  2008 07  recorded     75  2010-12-10
4  2008 07  recorded     66  2010-11-01
5  2008 12  recorded     62  2010-12-07
6  2008 12  recorded     60  2010-11-10
7  2008 12  recorded     60  2010-09-12

df_missed
        id  missed_score missed_date
0  2008 11            62  2010-08-01
1  2008 07            72  2010-10-20
2  2008 12            80  2010-07-23
```

I 'd like to add a row in the end for each group in 'df_recorded', e.g. Adding the same 'id=2008 11' and an new entry called 'missed' in the 'info' column, then adding the score and date by searching the df_missed table, so the result should look like this:

```
Target result:
         id      info  score        date
0   2008 11  recorded     98  2010-12-10
1   2008 11  recorded     68  2010-10-01
2   2008 11  recorded     79  2010-09-12
3   2008 11    missed     62  2010-08-01 # new record
4   2008 07  recorded     75  2010-12-10
5   2008 07  recorded     66  2010-11-01
6   2008 07    missed     72  2010-10-20 # new record
7   2008 12  recorded     62  2010-12-07
8   2008 12  recorded     60  2010-11-10
9   2008 12  recorded     60  2010-09-12
10  2008 12    missed     80  2010-07-23 # new record
```

I tried to code with loops but very slow and inefficient. So please help if you have any ideas to make it better. A great thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can simply rename the columns in the missing df and `concat`:

```
df_missed.columns = ["id", "score", "date"]

df = pd.concat([df_recorded,df_missed], ignore_index=True, sort=False).sort_values("id", ascending=False)
df.loc[df["info"].isnull(),"info"] = "missing"
print (df)

         id      info  score        date
5   2008 12  recorded     62  2010-12-07
6   2008 12  recorded     60  2010-11-10
7   2008 12  recorded     60  2010-09-12
10  2008 12   missing     80  2010-07-23
0   2008 11  recorded     98  2010-12-10
1   2008 11  recorded     68  2010-10-01
2   2008 11  recorded     79  2010-09-12
8   2008 11   missing     62  2010-08-01
3   2008 07  recorded     75  2010-12-10
4   2008 07  recorded     66  2010-11-01
9   2008 07   missing     72  2010-10-20
```

Comment: Thank you @Henry Yik, too good answer. I feel so bad for myself, your code is great and I can understand it well. But I just could not write it like you, maybe I don't have the talent. so sad..
Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import pandas as pd

df_recorded = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['2008 11', '2008 11', '2008 11', '2008 07', '2008 07', '2008 12', '2008 12', '2008 12'],
    'info': ['recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', 'recorded', ],
    'score': [98, 68, 79, 75, 66, 62, 60, 60],
    'date' : ['2010-12-10', '2010-10-01', '2010-09-12', '2010-12-10', '2010-11-01', '2010-12-07', '2010-11-10', '2010-09-12']
})

df_missed = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['2008 11', '2008 07', '2008 12'],
    'missed_score': [62, 72, 80],
    'missed_date': ['2010-08-01', '2010-10-20', '2010-07-23']
})
df_missed.rename(columns={'missed_score':'score','missed_date':'date'},inplace=True)

df_recorded=df_recorded.append(df_missed,ignore_index=True)
df_recorded=df_recorded.fillna('missed')
df_recorded.sort_values(by='id')
```

output

```
id  info    score   date
3   2008 07     recorded    75  2010-12-10
4   2008 07     recorded    66  2010-11-01
9   2008 07     missed  72  2010-10-20
0   2008 11     recorded    98  2010-12-10
1   2008 11     recorded    68  2010-10-01
2   2008 11     recorded    79  2010-09-12
8   2008 11     missed  62  2010-08-01
5   2008 12     recorded    62  2010-12-07
6   2008 12     recorded    60  2010-11-10
7   2008 12     recorded    60  2010-09-12
10  2008 12     missed  80  2010-07-23
```

Comment: Thank you @NAGA RAJ S, your answer is good, but also need to sort_values by id.